# Como executar um código python pelo anaconda prompt com php?

Tags: php, python, redes-neurais, keras

Pessoal segue a descrição para entendimento:

1 - Possuo o código de um classificador escrito em python

2 - Quero executá-lo a partir do php (shell_exec() por exemplo) mas não utilizando o prompt do windows e sim o anaconda prompt visto que, executando o python a partir do prompt do windows nao é identificada algumas bibliotecas instaladas pelo anaconda prompt como numpy, keras... etc.

3. Essa foi a solução que pensei, básicamente rodar codigo python a partir do php usando o anaconda prompt. Já pesquisei mas não achei uma solução.

Estou aberto a novas sugestões para executar essa tarefa , visto que sou leigo e desconheço uma forma de fazer isso.

Comment: Por que precisa executar a partir do PHP?

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que  seu problema seja bastante semelhante em executar um prompt que não seja o prompt padrão do Windows, você pode executar o prompt semelhante a execução do powershell no exemplo abaixo, substitua pelo caminho do anaconda e acrescente os parâmetros que o anaconda aceita.

Referência:

[Run a Powershell script from PHP](https://www.itdroplets.com/run-a-powershell-script-from-php/)